Not able to download and save huggingface model - jinaai/jina-reranker-v2-base-multilingual
I am trying to download and save the following model from huggingface for later use. Here is the snippet.
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, 
AutoTokenizer,AutoModelForCausalLM

model_name='jinaai/jina-reranker-v2-base-multilingual'

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(model_name)


model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, trust_remote_code=True)
model.save_pretrained(f"model/{model_name}")

Getting this error
ValueError: Unrecognized configuration class <class 'transformers_modules.jina- 
reranker-v2-base-multilingual.configuration_xlm_roberta.XLMRobertaFlashConfig'> for 
this kind of AutoModel: AutoModelForCausalLM.
Model type should be one of BartConfig, BertConfig, BertGenerationConfig, 
BigBirdConfig, BigBirdPegasusConfig.......

Folder Structure for the project
root/aimodel.py (where the code snippet is written)
root/jinai/jina-reranker-v2-base-multilingual/ < all files from this url - [https://huggingface.co/jinaai/jina-reranker-v2-base-multilingual/tree/main][1] >


This model is a sentence pair classification model that was fine-tuned on multilingual sentence similarity/retrieval. It is not a generic text generation model, so you can not load it as such. Therefore you should use AutoModelForSequenceClassification instead of AutoModelForCausalLM, see the documentation.
Here's an example of how to use it:
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    'jinaai/jina-reranker-v2-base-multilingual',
    torch_dtype="auto",
    trust_remote_code=True,
).to('cuda').eval()

candidates = ["the car goes fast", "the car goes slow", "the bicycle goes slow"]
sentence_pairs = [["the car drives fast", doc] for doc in candidates]

scores = model.compute_score(sentence_pairs, max_length=1024)
print(scores)

> [0.7217432260513306, 0.14128141105175018, 0.0384661927819252]

If you want to use/fine-tune a model with AutoModelForCausalLM, check out the list of text generation model on huggingface: https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=text-generation&sort=downloads
